# bulk insert sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, bulk-load

When using the T-SQL Bulk insert command from SQL Server Management Stuidio, I am getting this error randomly. Not everytime. Sometimes it would work completely fine and sometimes it throws me the below error.

Error:
Cannot bulk load because the file "\xxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\xxxxxxx.xsd" could not be opened. Operating system error code 1326(Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.).

I can access the share drive from my machine and in fact, I was the one who kept that file in that particular share drive.

Comment: This question seems to be already answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016799/sql-bulk-insert-file-does-not-exist

Comment: Edited my question to be more precise. Have a look and let me know your thoughts. Thanks!!